# Can FFTW use an alternate user supplied malloc and free?

Tags: malloc, free, fftw

I'm working in an environment where I need to use alternate work-alike calls to malloc() and free(). I'd like to make calls into FFTW, but if FFTW internally calls malloc() and free() for it's own purposes it will screw up the memory management environment that I am in, so I need a way to tell FFTW to use alternate functions I supply instead of malloc and free. How do I do that?

Comment: What allocator do you want to use? Many of them can be activated via LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: MATLAB's mxMalloc / mxFree.  This code needs to be able to be compiled both as a standalone executable, and as a MATLAB MEX library.  I'd like it to run as identically as possible between the two situations.  I need FFTW for standalone; I'd prefer to use it for MATLAB MEX as well for consistency and simplicity of code.

Answer (score 1):

I sure hope your underlying mex compiler is gcc / GNU binutils.  If not, you might want to change mex compilers so that it is.  This answer is very much specific to GNU ld...

Add the following to the code that gets compiled with your mexFunction:

```
void *
__wrap_malloc(size_t size)
{
    return mxMalloc(size);
}


void
__wrap_free(void *ptr)
{
    return mxFree(ptr);
}


void *
__wrap_memalign(size_t alignment __attribute__((__unused__)), size_t size)
{
    return mxMalloc(size);
}
```

BTW, I got that list of three functions to wrap by doing an objdump -T libfftw3.so, and looking for `*UND*` entries for heap management functions.  Those were the only three that showed up.

Now, add the following to your mex command line:

```
CLIBS='-Wl,--wrap=malloc,--wrap=free,--wrap=memalign,-Bstatic,-lfftw3,-Bdynamic $CLIBS'
```

By forcing the linker to bring in libfftw3 statically, it can wrap the specified heap calls with your custom wrappers that redirect to MATLAB's heap management functions.

If you wanted to be fancy, you could enforce the alignment manually in the memalign() wrapper, and return a properly aligned pointer, but then you'd have to track each allocation to undo the pointer change at free() time.  I'm just naively assuming MATLAB's allocator will return pointers that are already zero mod the maximum useful alignment, thinking that MATLAB's need for that is similar to FFTW's.

Also, remember to destroy all your plans and fftw_cleanup() on the way out of your mexFunction.  MATLAB will force-free anything your mexFunction (or FFTW called by your mexFunction) allocated upon return of your mexFunction, unless you explicitly mexMakeMemoryPersistent() it.